# jqGrid - is it possible to change the searchable content of a cell?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jqgrid

Using `jqGrid` i got a `colModel` like this:

```
colModel:[
    {name:'id',index:'id', width:50, search: true, sort: true, editable: false},
    {name:'number',index:'number', width:150, search: true, sort: true, editable: false},
    {name:'product',index:'product', width:300, search: true, sort: true, editable: false},
    {name:'pdf_dropdown',index:'pdf_dropdown', width:500, search: true, sort: true, editable: false}
]
```

my column named 'pdf_dropdown' gets it content by a customization of mine which is feeding a `html select object` into it:

```
$row['pdf_dropdown'] = '<select name="my_select"><option value="4">Some Text</option>........</select>';
```

so far this is working fine and i can also use my `jQuery` code on the `select` without problems. But when it comes to searching i obviously want `jqGrid` to just search for the content inside the `selected <option>` tag.

is it possible to set something like a custom content for a cell in `jqGrid` which is used for searching only?

something like for example (in my `colModel`):

```
{name:'pdf_dropdown',index:'pdf_dropdown',search_content:'pdf_dropdown_searchable', ...}
```

where i can feed the content for 'pdf_dropdown_searchable' with `$row['pdf_dropdown_searchable']` in my corresponding `php` file?

any help or ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There is an option called *searchoptions* but is applicable only for stype select fields. Something like this:

```
   {name:'pdf_dropdown',index:'pdf_dropdown', edittype:"select", formatter:"select", 
            stype: 'select', width:500, search: true, sort: true, editable: false,             
             searchoptions:{dataUrl:'yourUrl'}}
```

For all the options, look at:

[http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:search_config](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asearch_config)

Comment: thanks for the hint. i will check this out tomorrow.